# What is the meaning of the Composer Version constraint `>=N.N.N`

Tags: composer-php

What is the highest version of PHP allowed by the following composer package manager version constraint?

```
 "php": "^5.5.9|>=7.0.8"
```

---

[The docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints) say that:-

- `^5.5.9` means `>=5.5.9 <6.0.0` (read: "greater or equal to 5.5.9 **AND** less than 6.0.0)
- `|` is probably the same as `||` which means **OR**

But what does `>=7.0.8` expand to?  In the [stability section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stability-constraints) the docs say that

> Composer will default internally to `-dev` or `-stable`, depending on the operator(s) used

and gives an example of `>=1.2` being treated internally as `>=1.2.0.0-dev` but it doesn't say how `>=1.2.0` is treated.  It is also not clear whether this is an open ended constraint.

So does the constraint allow any version of PHP at or above 7.0.8?  Does it only allow versions at or above 7.0.8 but below 8.0.0?  Does it allow `-dev`?  Would it allow `8.0-dev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "php": ">=7.0.8"

Would mean *anything* above or equal to 7.0.8, yes also 8.0.0

Taken from the composer documentation:

> "vendor/package": ">=1.3.2", // anything above or equal to 1.3.2

I think the documentation states that pretty clear ;)
Note that php is not a real package in the composer repository.

Test your package e.g. with this tool:
https://semver.mwl.be/#?package=sensio%2Fframework-extra-bundle&version=%3E%3D3.0.2&minimum-stability=stable

Comment: "I think the documentation states that pretty clear ;)"
Hah, I suppose you're right :)